# Use result of star search (super-star) in Vim ex command

Tags: vim

I'd like to run an ex command which operates on the keyword currently under the cursor (like pressing <kbd>*</kbd>, the so-called [super-star](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Searching#Searching_for_the_current_word) search).

Specifically, I'd like to run `Ack` with the current keyword.

How can I perform a <kbd>*</kbd> search in command (ex) mode?

Comment: @rkta That's great. I didn't know that. `Ctrl-r Ctrl-w` still has other use cases, I'm sure.

Answer (score -1):

As described [in the searching article on Fandom](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Searching#More_searching):

> Use Ctrl-r Ctrl-w for a *cword*, or Ctrl-r Ctrl-a for a *cWORD*

So you could remap, say, Ctrl+F to perform an `ack` search on the current word like this:

```
nnoremap <c-F> :Ack!<space><c-r><c-w>
```

Leaving the command with no `<CR>` afterwards allows you to edit the search term if you need to.